# Is the number of operators always one less than the number of values in an arithmetic Reverse Polish Notation expression with only binary operators?

Tags: parsers, arithmetic

Is the number of operators always one less than the number of values in an arithmetic Reverse Polish Notation expression with only **binary operators**?

This question seems very trivial, but I don't know if the statement is necessarily true for all N > 1 where N is the number of values. It seems intuitively true because any expression with more than one binary operator can be expressed as a combination of two different expressions through induction, but I'm not very confident.

Comment: *I don't need a proof.* This is the wrong sentiment when trying to learn computer science. We're not here to help you with your homework – we're here to help you understand the material, so that you can do your homework yourself next time.

Comment: I'm really sorry; I was mostly trying to ask if this statement is even true in the first place. I didn't really want to ask for a proof because that will waste people's time since it's probably trivial to everyone here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RPN expressions have stack semantics: a **value** pushes a number onto the stack, whereas a binary **operator** pops two values and pushes one back, for a net loss of one element. At the start of an expression the stack is empty, and at the end there is exactly one value – the result.

Now let $V$ be the number of values in the expression, and $B$ be the number of binary operators. Then at the end of the expression, the stack contains $V-B$ values. Since there should be exactly one value remaining, we conclude that $V-B = 1$, or $B = V-1$.

---

Another way to see this is using structural induction. As you mention, every expression is either a value or is obtained from two expressions combined using a binary operator. Let's prove by induction on the number of values and operators appearing in the expression that $V = B+1$ (in the terminology of the preceding section).

When the expression consists of just a value, $B=0$ and $V=1$, so $V = B+1$. When the expression consists of a binary operator together with two other expressions $E_1,E_2$, we have $V = V(E_1)+V(E_2)$ and $B = B(E_1)+B(E_2)+1$ (I hope the notation is clear). By induction, $V(E_1) = B(E_1)+1$ and $V(E_2) = B(E_2)+1$, so
$$ V = V(E_1) + V(E_2) = B(E_1) + 1 + B(E_2) + 1 = B + 1. $$

Answer (score 1):

A simple inductive argument will work here. Expressions in RPN can be defined recursively by using the grammar:

```
E: operand
E: E E operator
```

Where `E` is an expression, `operand` is a number and `operator` is a binary operator.

The base case is when the expression is just a number. In this case the number of operators is clearly one less than the number of operands.

Let E be an expression of length `n > 1` and assume that the statement is true for expressions of length `< n` (`n` here is the number of operands). The expression is of the form `E1 E2 operator`. The first two expressions have smaller lengths and so we have:

```
o1 = n1 - 1.
o2 = n2 - 1.
o = o1 + o2 + 1 = n1 + n2 - 2 + 1 = n - 1 (we add 1 for the `operator` in `E1 E2 operator`).
```

`o` stands for number of operators.
`n` stands for number of operands.